# Displaying images in HTML as content inside ionic 2 app

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

This is an Ionic 2 app.
The app fetches data using REST API and in JSON format.
One of the field is sent as HTML content from the server. This is currently being displayed using

```
 <div [innerHTML] = "'<p>' + eventMoreDetails.DescriptionHtml + '</p>'"></div>
```

This has image which is embeded in this html like

```
<p><img src="/Resources/Documents/bikers.jpg" title="" alt="" width="600" height="287" border="0"><br></p>"
```

Since this resolves to  http://localhost:8100/Resources/Documents/bikers.jpg instead of actual url of the API, the is not getting loaded.

But I am not sure how to parse this content and replace it with API's url prefix.

[image: Browser screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Just need to replace the image URL before binding as the following

```
var find = '/Resource/Documents/';
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');

str = eventMoreDetails.DescriptionHtml.replace(re, 'http://YOUR_URL/Resource/Documents/');
```

On the server probably the image will always save at a specific folder. It will depend on your data to changed the path to replace.

Comment: It worked partially for me, but problem was it was replacing only the first occurrence. I wasn't sure how to get it done using regex and passing /g global parameter. So I ended up using somestring.split('oldString').join('newString');

Comment: Ops I forgot. If you still want to use replace for all occurrences in a string, please check my updated answer :D